# Security / Antivirus software for Pi OS - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: security, malware

I want to use a Pi 4 for internet banking. Now that hackers are specifically targetting Linux with new exploits i want a good security product.

I have contacted Linux security software vendors such as ESET but they do not support Pi OS.  Apparently the ARM chipset is a problem.

I am told that ClamAV is not adequate for Internet Banking.

Does anyone know of  a security software vendor that supports Pi OS?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Seems to me the value of AV software is mostly in the database they keep.  Why is ClamAV "not adequate for Internet Banking"?  Without having done any research, I'd guess that ClamAV probably does have the biggest malware DB available for linux, meaning it is your best bet.

Comment: ClamAV is not worth the price you didn't pay for it. It's useless for Linux malware, it's mostly for Windows malware that's hosted on a Linux based fileshare. ClamAV offer no protection for things that might attack a Raspberry.

Comment: Fair enough -- I know the primary purpose is on linux mailservers to filter stuff before it gets downloaded to Windows clients.  However, I'm not sure that there are any serious alternatives.   But I guess that is the question.  Of course, almost certainly **you can use everything**, you don't have to just choose one.  One ring to bind them all is a nice thought, but four or five is probably better...

Comment: That said, perhaps the root issue is that security on linux is mostly done with a combination of containerization and selinux.  Unfortunately last I checked (years ago), the stock Raspbian kernel doesn't include the latter.  And in any case making that work on a desktop system is going to be a non-starter for most people.  Point about the "root issue" is that that's very niche-in-a-corner (linux desktop users), and they are probably fine with proprietary stuff like ESET.  So again, ClamAV + whatever else (rootkithunter etc) you can get is probably the best you are going to get on a Pi.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks and Dougie. I'm surprised this requirement hasn't been met given that the pi 4 is absolutely powerful enough to serve as a consumer workstation. But it looks like security would be a significant work overhead and questionable effectiveness so I think I'll need to go a different way. Thanks to you both for your advice.